# A possible Grothendieck Topology/ Coverage of $\mathbf{Top}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, category-theory, sheaf-theory, grothendieck-topologies

For any topological space $X$ we have a canonical functor from its category (poset) of open subsets $\mathcal{O}(X)$ to category of topological spaces $\mathbf{Top}$ defined in the obvious way. This induces a functor between presheaf categories $$L_X : \mathbf{Set}^{\mathbf{Top}^{\mathbf{op}}}\to \mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{O}(X)^{\mathbf{op}}}$$ and we can define a presheaf $F\in \mathbf{Set}^{\mathbf{Top}^{\mathbf{op}}}$ to be a sheaf if $L_XF$ is a sheaf for all $X.$
In fact, the same strategy works for any category $\mathcal{C}$ that associate with a family of functors $\mathcal{O}(X)\to\mathcal{C}$ for all $X\in\mathbf{Top}.$

I have read that the minimum structure require for the notion of sheaves is a [coverage.](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coverage)
Now, my question is, what is the underneath coverage or Grothendieck topology over $\mathbf{Top}$ induced by functors $L_X,$ if any?
If there is no such coverage/ Grothendieck topology, what are the other occasions that we can define sheaves without a coverage and a Grothendieck topology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no trouble: there is a Grothendieck topology on $\mathrm{Top}$ in which the coverings are jointly surjective families of open inclusions, and your notion of sheaf is precisely the same as the notion of sheaf for this covering. There *is* an issue in talking about the category of presheaves on $\mathrm{Top}$, since the latter is a large category; you can handle this either by restricting the size of your spaces or by allowing presheaves with values in large sets, or, if you really want to consider presheaves on arbitrary spaces valued in small sets, by giving up a few of the nice properties of legitimate Grothendieck toposes.

Comment: How do we know this is exactly the Grothendieck topology described in your answer?

Comment: A covering in Top is a family $U_i\to X$ of open inclusions which are jointly surjective. This is a covering in $\mathcal O_X$. Conversely, every covering in the poset is a covering in Top.

Comment: For me, it seems like the corresponding topology of Top induced by the family of jointly surjective, topological embeddings. Why do you think "open inclusions" are enough?

Comment: @Bumblebee Well, I proved that every jointly surjective family of open inclusions in Top comes from a cover in some $\mathcal O_X$ and conversely. Furthermore it’s merely the definition of continuous function that open inclusions are stable under pullback, so the suggested families do form a coverage on Top. Why don’t you explain where you see some non-open embedding appearing here?